# Retrieving current network-based location in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need to find the current country I'm in for a WP7 app. How do I go about it?

Thanks,
Alex Dvorak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To translate the lattitude/longitude to an address which should give you the country, you may want to try the reverse geocoding using geocode service from bing maps.
Article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879136.aspx
Geocode service metadata url : http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/geocodeservice.svc?wsdl

Answer (score 2):

There is a [howto on MSDN on how to use location service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431782%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) - if you're only interested in the country, you'll only need the [Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geopositionaccuracy%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) accuracy, but you will need to plug that into some webservice/internal DB to translate to an actual country name

Comment: Do you know of any such service I can use?